# How to handle null values with xgboost converted to pmml?

Tags: scikit-learn, null, xgboost, pmml, openscoring

I have a xgboost model trained on numerical data containing np.nan values. 
I converted xgboost model to pmml with [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) library.

I test pmml with [openscoring](https://github.com/openscoring/openscoring) library. 
On data without nulls pmml makes prediction and gives the same results as model.
On data with nulls pmml can't make prediction and return JSONDecodeError.

How should I modify pmml to handle nulls and return the same prediction as the original one (xgboost model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On data with nulls pmml can't make prediction and return JSONDecodeError.

JSONDecodeError is related to Openscoring, and is not related to PMML, XGBoost or Scikit-Learn at any level.

The root cause of this JSONDecodeError should be explained in Openscoring's server-side log file. Given it's a "decoding error", then most probably your input to it is invalid and/or malformed.

Comment: That's right. I changed np.nan in my input data to string "NA", and it passed through Openscoring. Then in PMML it caused invalid value for "NA". I could handle it with attributes `invalidValueTreatment="asMissing"`  and `missingValueStrategy="none"` Thanks for helps!

Comment: When converting XGBoost models to PMML using the `sklearn2pmml` package, then it's possible to customize the representation and handling of missing values using `sklearn2pmml.decoration.CategoricalDomain` and `ContinuousDomain` pseudo-transformers - see the documentation. This way you can eliminate the need to modify PMML files manually.